# Retrieving data from a dictionary based on dropdown menu choices using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show some data based on the client's choice from a dropdown menu using javascript. The data is inside a dictionary. How can I retrieve it and present it? Here's my code so far.
The HTML file:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="model.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="countryProperties">
    <h4>1. Select two countries for comparison: <br><br>
        <select class="round" id="c1" name="Select1" >
            <option value="hide">--Select the first country to compare--</option>
            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
            <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
            <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
            <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
        </select>

        <select class="round" id="c2" name="Select2" onclick >
            <option value="hide">--Select the second country to compare--</option>
            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
            <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
            <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
            <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
        </select>
    </h4>
    <h4>2. Select category for comparison:</h4>
    <select name="categoryDropdown">
        <option value="hide">--Select the category to compare--</option>
        <option value="Population">Population</option>
        <option value="Area">Area</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id="result"></p>


<!-- Add main JS file. -->
<script src="model.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my js code:

```
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("c1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("c2").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = typeof(x);

}
var countryData = {
    "Germany": {name: "Germany", area: "357,022 sq km", popul: "80,722,792"},
    "Norway": {name: "Norway", area: "323,802 sq km", popul: "5,265,158"},
    "Greece": {name: "Greece", area: "43,094 sq km", popul: "5,593,785"},
    "Poland": {name: "Poland", area: "312,685 sq km", popul: "38,523,261"},
    "Denmark": {name: "Denmark", area: "43,094 sq km", popul: "5,593,785"}
};
console.log(typeof(countryData.Germany))
```

Here's the whole thing: https://jsfiddle.net/foha1p7w/

I want to show a juxtaposition of both the countries' properties. What can I do here? Thanks

Comment: The jsfiddle is not the same as the code you have written here.

Comment: @DouglasTylerGordon My bad. That was an old draft. The link should work now.

Comment: I don't really see much of an attempt to write the code that actually does the "juxtaposition". There are innumerable ways of comparing them; display the values one after the other; show them in a grid; show a chart illustrating the difference.

Comment: You can't include `model.js` at the end of your file since your `button` element needs to know about `myFunction()`: https://jsfiddle.net/u49ep9uc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't shown how you want to compare, a very crude way to comparing would be just showing values side by side like this

```
var countryData = {
    "Germany": {name: "Germany", area: "357,022 sq km", popul: "80,722,792"},
    "Norway": {name: "Norway", area: "323,802 sq km", popul: "5,265,158"},
    "Greece": {name: "Greece", area: "43,094 sq km", popul: "5,593,785"},
    "Poland": {name: "Poland", area: "312,685 sq km", popul: "38,523,261"},
    "Denmark": {name: "Denmark", area: "43,094 sq km", popul: "5,593,785"}
};

myFunction = function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("c1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("c2").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c3").value;

    document.getElementById("result").innerText = x + ' = ' + countryData[x][c] + ' and ' + y + ' = ' + countryData[y][c];

}
```

Change your compare dropdown like this

```
<select id="c3" name="categoryDropdown">
        <option value="hide">--Select the category to compare--</option>
        <option value="popul">Population</option>
        <option value="area">Area</option>
    </select>
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/vabii/93wqmkh3/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just didn't know how to get access to countryData. Stupid of me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a little vague - I'm not sure how you want this data presented, but here is probably the simplest thing you can do: https://jsfiddle.net/ax2818ya/. I just used string interpolation to make a sentence.

Here's the main function:

```
  function myFunction() {    
    var countryOne = document.getElementById("c1").value;
    var countryTwo = document.getElementById("c2").value;
    var comparison = document.getElementById("comparison").value;
    if (comparison === "Area") {
      comparison = "area"
    } else if (comparison === "Population") {
      comparison = "popul"
    }
    const output = `${countryOne} has ${comparison} ${countryData[countryOne][comparison]} and ${countryTwo} has ${comparison} ${countryData[countryTwo][comparison]}`
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = output;
}
```

Notice that I had to change the value of "comparison" to match the key names in your object. Ignore the fact that I put everything on the window, I'm just bad at JSFiddle. Be careful and consider what happens if one of these fields is left blank and the user clicks submit. As a general tip, try and be descriptive as possible when naming variables - don't just use `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have a much better idea.